# UNIX ZFS ACLs aren't being honored

Tags: unix, solaris, acl, zfs

I am attempting to set special ACLs on all files and directories in a tree and they don't seem to be honored. I'm running Solaris 5.10. The ACLs are described by 'man chmod'.

I am setting ACLs such that modification of file attributes (A) or file ACLs (W) is not allowed. But still I am allowed to modify them - and once I do, all the special ACLs on a file disappear. For example:

```
/test> ls -lV filename
-r-x------+  1 svcdiscprod sasuser      355 Dec 13 09:56 filename
              owner@:r-xp-Da-R-c--s:fd----:allow
    user:svcdiscprod:r-xp-Da-R-c--s:fd----:allow
           everyone@:------a-R-c--s:------:allow
/test> chmod 666 filename             # <== This command should be blocked
/test> ls -lV filename
-rw-rw-rw-   1 svcdiscprod sasuser      355 Dec 13 09:56 filename
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think the command should be blocked?

Per [the ZFS Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E37384/gbace.html#scrolltoc):

> **Setting ACLs on ZFS Files**
>
> ...
>
> - The owner of the file is granted the `write_acl` permission    unconditionally, even if the permission is explicitly denied. ...